# Математические вычисления в css

Tags: html, css

Приветствую

```
//css - вот так можно
width:100%;
width:980px;

//css - а можно сделать вот так?
width:50%-1px;//( 50 процентов ширины экрана минус 1 пиксель )
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Да, конечно:

```
width: calc(50% - 1px);
```

Comment: @AlexandrBreus - ты гениален!!1 Спасибо!

Comment: Посмотрите еще на box-sizing; В некоторых ситуациях с комбинацией ширин в процентах и отступов в пикселях это может помочь. И обратите внимание на уровень поддержки. Строить что-то важное, вроде основного лейаута сайта основываясь на новых свойствах возможно не лучшая идея.